# No se envia correos con phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Hola a todos tengo un pequeño problema con con Phpmailer , no logro enviar el correo , los *** son el usuario y contraseña por obvias razones se publican así pero no creo que eso es el problema ya que tengo acceso al correo , entonces no se cual es el problema e intentado con todos los puertos pero no logro conseguirlo

Me sale el siguiente error : SMTP Error: Could not authenticate” in PHPMailer

```
<?php

$Nombre = $_POST['Nombre'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Mensaje = $_POST['Mensaje'];

if ($Nombre=='' || $Email=='' || $Mensaje==''){ 

echo  "<script>alert('Los campos con (*) son obligatorios.');location.href ='index.html';</script>";

}else{


    require 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
    require 'phpmailer/class.smtp.php'; //incluimos la clase para envíos por SMTP
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->FromName = $Nombre; 
    $mail->AddAddress($Email); // Dirección a la que llegaran los mensajes.
   
// Aquí van los datos que apareceran en el correo que reciba
            
    $mail->IsHTML(true);     
    $mail->Subject  =  "Contacto";
    $mail->Body     =  "Nombre: $Nombre \n<br />".    
    "Email: $Email \n<br />".    
    "Mensaje: $Mensaje \n<br />";
    
    

// Datos del servidor SMTP
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "smtp.office365.com";
    $mail->Port = "587";
    /*tls true*/
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->Username = '******';
    $mail->Password = '******';
    
    
    if ($mail->Send())
    echo "<script>alert('Formulario enviado exitosamente, le responderemos lo más pronto posible.');location.href ='index.html';</script>";
    else
    echo "no";

}

?>
```

Comment: Debes de permitir el acceso a tu cuenta de correo, al igual como pasa con Google, tienes que habilitar el acceso a apps

Comment: Haz un debug completo de la autenticación poniendo `$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;` Ahí debería decirte con claridad cuál es el problema. Si no logras resolverlo agrega ese debug a la pregunta, sin mostrar datos sensibles.